# Python implementation of a singly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

This is my code for the implementation of a singly linked list in Python:

```
class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, item):
        try:
            if not item:
                raise ValueError
            self.size += 1
            if self.root is None:
                self.root = Node(item)
            else:
                p = Node(item)
                p.next = self.root
                self.root = p
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Cannot add None item to a list')

    def remove(self, index):
        try:
            if index < 0 or index >= self.size:
                raise ValueError

            current = self.root
            count = 0
            while count < index:
                current = current.next
                count += 1
            current.next = current.next.next
            self.size -= 1
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the list')

    def __sizeof__(self):
        return self.size


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        try:
            if not data:
                raise ValueError
            self.data = data
            self.next = None
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Node cannot be instantiated without an item')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `raise` + `except` + `raise` = `raise`

```
def remove(self, index):
    try:
        if index < 0 or index >= self.size:
            raise ValueError

            ...

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the list')
```

It make no sense to `except` and `raise` again, simplify to:

```
if index < 0 or index >= self.size:
    raise IndexError('Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the list')

...
```

The function will look like:

```
def insert(self, item):
    if item is None:
        raise ValueError('Cannot add None item to a list')
    self.size += 1
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = Node(item)
    else:
        p = Node(item)
        p.next = self.root
        self.root = p
```

#### `for` instead of counting loop

`for` is a more streamlined way of looping `n` times than a `while` loop:

```
        count = 0
        while count < index:
            current = current.next
            count += 1
```

Becomes:

```
for _ in range(index):
    current = current.next
```

(Please note `_` is a convention meaning the value will not be used)

Comment: I'm new to Python, as regards the try and except, what do I put in the except block in this case.

Comment: @Stacker nothing, you just remove it

Comment: My editor gives a compilation time squiggly if I remove the except block

Comment: @Stacker added example

Comment: If you have "Index cannot...", you could use `IndexError` instead of `ValueError`: the index is wrong, not the value.

Comment: The condition `if not item` doesn't only test `None` but any value evaluated to `False`: `False` itself, nul int or float, empty string, empty containers, user-defined type which have `__bool__` or `__len__` methods and `Ellipsis`...

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Corrected as you suggested

Answer (score 4):

Docstrings would be a good idea.  It is not immediately obvious, for example, that `insert()` manipulates the *head* of the list.  Also, "head" is a more common term when talking about linked lists; "root" would be more appropriate for graphs.

Judging by `raise ValueError('Cannot add None item to a list')`, this is wrong:

> ```
> if not item:
>    raise ValueError
> ```

It looks like you intended to forbid `None` from being inserted, but you are actually also preventing `0`, `False`, or empty strings from being inserted as well.

`raise ValueError` is poor style as well, if what you really mean to do is `raise ValueError('Cannot add None item to a list')`.  But that seems to be redundant with the check that you wrote in the `Node` constructor.

---

Your `remove()` method is unable to remove the last element in the list.

Counting loops, such as the one in `remove()`, are idiomatically done using `range()` or `xrange()`.

You can use a double-ended inequality to check that the `index` is in range.  I'd raise an `IndexError` instead of a `ValueError` if the index is out of range.

```
if not 0 <= index < self.size:
    raise IndexError('Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the list')
```

---

The code would be simplified by having the `Node` constructor accept an optional `next` parameter.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError('Node value cannot be None')
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, value):
        """Insert a value (which cannot be None) at the head of the list."""
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)
        self.size += 1
```